# How to Create .Ipa file with Xcode 12 without developer account and how do I download it on Macbook Air without Itunes?

Tags: ios, xcode12.3

- I want to share an app without developer account and without attaching simulators to the Macbook air

Comment: You need a developer account to do this, it is not possible to sign an `.ipa` without a valid developer account.

Comment: Do i have to had developer account to create and share .ipa file as well?

Comment: can you share me details to create and download .ipa file without developer account?

Comment: You cannot, you need a developer account.